# overwriting html <input type=hidden> values

Tags: html, django

Im creating the payment form for a django ecommerce page and i ran into a situation dealing with saved credit card information.

If i want to signal to my server what action to use, do i need to wrap the first input and button in its own form?  or can i use the code below?

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated and user.get_profile.stripe_customer_id %}
        <input type="hidden" name="action=" value="delete_card"/>
        <button type="submit">Use Another Card</button>

        <input type="hidden" name="action=" value="pay_saved_card"/>


 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override a hidden field with HTML, except in the sense that you can make another control send a parameter with the same name and then server-side check the situation.

The simplest way for the case is to have a checkbox like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="action" value="delete_card" id="othercard" />
<label for="othercard">Use Another Card</label>
```

without using the hidden field. The server-side code should then just test for the presence of an `action` attribute with value `delete_card`.

Using an equals sign as in `name="action="` is possibly but not common or needed: when the form is submitted, data items of the form name=value are generated, so you would get `action==delete_card`.

Comment: Do any browsers discard duplicate name parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for a form to submit or cancel one would add following in the form.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Save" />
```

And depending upon `request.POST['action']` in django view you would either you process to save the form or do cancel processing.

Comment: Don't think it's a good idea. What happens if user just press 'enter' in input field?